# Website interface designer tool

Tags: interface

I work on a project, I don't have to build an actual website, I only have to build three "screens"(pages) of my "website" (so these can be simply .jpeg or .pdf), I don't need to have actual HTML code. So I am looking for a tool that allows me to easily to that, (some drag and drop functionalities). The "pages" don't look that complex, but I also need to drag a few check boxes and radio buttons.

Do you know a good tool to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using http://cacoo.com for design simpler layout. You can try it.

Answer (score 0):

[Balsamiq](http://www.balsamiq.com/) is a good mock up tool for showing what pages might look like.

Comment: From what I've seen on youtube, al those components that you drag on the screen look a bit "funny", I don''t want them to look like they are "Paper prototype", but actual screenshots of my website.

Answer (score 0):

Sketchflow would be a good tool as would [balsamiq mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/)

Comment: From what I've seen on youtube, al those components that you drag on the screen look a bit "funny", I don''t want them to look like they are "Paper prototype", but actual screenshots of my website.

Comment: they do look like paper prototypes that is the idea.